# Convert integer (epoch time in ms) to PrimitiveDateTime

Tags: postgresql, datetime, rust, timestamp

I have been trying but it is difficult as the types don't match perfectly.

My current attempt:

```rust
use ::time::{PrimitiveDateTime, OffsetDateTime};
use std::time::{UNIX_EPOCH, Duration};
use chrono::{DateTime, Utc, NaiveDateTime};


fn my_func() {
    let timestamp:u64 = 1696443084 // {integer from http request, representing timestamp in ms since epoch}
    let d:SystemTime = UNIX_EPOCH + Duration::from_secs(timestamp/1000);
    let datetime:DateTime<Utc> = DateTime::<Utc>::from(d); // ideally want to replace this line with one where I get a DateTime (and not DateTime<Utc>) from the integer.
    let created_at:PrimitiveDateTime = PrimitiveDateTime::new(datetime.date_naive(), datetime.time());
}
```

My error message (compilation) is the following:

```
106 | ... = PrimitiveDateTime::new(datetime.date_naive(), datetime.time(...
    |       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ---------------------  --------------- expected `Time`, found `NaiveTime`
    |                              |
    |                              expected `Date`, found `NaiveDate`
    |
note: associated function defined here
   --> /.../time-0.3.23/src/primitive_date_time.rs:92:18
    |
92  |     pub const fn new(date: ...
    |                  ^^^
```

I need to use [PrimitiveDateTime](https://docs.rs/time/latest/time/struct.PrimitiveDateTime.html) because this is how timestamp is stored inside the psql DB.

Comment: [There is no `PrimitiveDateTime` in `chrono`](https://docs.rs/chrono/latest/chrono/?search=PrimitiveDateTime). Please create a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and state for each type which crate it comes from.

Comment: No, this is not a MRE, this is missing at least some important `use`s that we cannot fill ourselves. We can't read your mind. Also, the error message is not the full message. And please don't put the error of an IDE but of `cargo check`, it contains more details.

Comment: Okay fair points. Will edit

Comment: What is `PrimitiveDateTime`?

Comment: Why are you mixing `time` and `chrono`? Use either, not both.

Comment: Was triggered by the compiler so I imported both

Comment: also `chrono` is the way I know to get a DateTime<Utc> from an integer

Comment: You should not. Both `time` and `chrono` are datetime libraries, and mixing them will just make you scratch your head. If you're forces to use `time` by use DB, use only it (unless it can't fulfill your needs, as it is less rich than `chrono`).

Comment: You are right. Hopefully I don't have to use `chrono` as I want to convert the integer to `DateTime` ( and not `DateTime<Utc>`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`chrono` has a method to convert ms since epoch to `NaiveDateTime`](https://docs.rs/chrono/latest/chrono/naive/struct.NaiveDateTime.html#method.from_timestamp_millis)... but `time` doesn't.

After a lot of research, I've found that is has a method to convert them to `OffsetDateTime`: [`from_unix_timestamp_nanos()`](https://docs.rs/time/latest/time/struct.OffsetDateTime.html#method.from_unix_timestamp_nanos) (there are only methods for seconds and nanoseconds, none for milliseconds). But there are no methods to convert an `OffsetDateTime` to `PrimitiveDateTime`, however `PrimitiveDateTime::new(dt.date(), dt.time())` seems to work.

So:

```rust
use time::{OffsetDateTime, PrimitiveDateTime};

fn main() {
    let timestamp: u64 = 1696443084; // {integer from http request, representing timestamp in ms since epoch}
    let created_at =
        OffsetDateTime::from_unix_timestamp_nanos(i128::from(timestamp) * 1_000_000).unwrap();
    let created_at = PrimitiveDateTime::new(created_at.date(), created_at.time());
    dbg!(created_at);
}
```

Comment: Amazing! Thanks a lot :)